# Json data Convert to C# Class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following JSON which I need to deserialize:

```
 [
      {
        "Facility": "H&S 01",
        "Address": [ "5999 Cerritos Ave." ],
        "City": [ "anaheim" ],
        "State": [ "ca" ],
        "ZipCode": [ 92831 ],
        "AQDMID": [ 1 ],
        "Jan": 222.0,
        "Feb": 434.0,
        "March": 343.0,
        "April": 431.0,
        "May": 222.0,
        "June": 345.0,
        "July": 666.0,
        "Aug": 643.0,
        "Sep": 0.0,
        "Oct": 0.0,
        "Nov": 0.0,
        "Dec": 0.0,
        "Total": 3306.0
      },
      {
        "Facility": "H&S 02",
        "Address": [ "1515 N. Garey Ave." ],
        "City": [ "hshsh" ],
        "State": [ "ca" ],
        "ZipCode": [ 92831 ],
        "AQDMID": [ 2 ],
        "Jan": 122.0,
        "Feb": 234.0,
        "March": 234.0,
        "April": 263.0,
        "May": 234.0,
        "June": 124.0,
        "July": 223.0,
        "Aug": 444.0,
        "Sep": 122.0,
        "Oct": 211.0,
        "Nov": 343.0,
        "Dec": 423.0,
        "Total": 2977.0
      }
    ]
```

I used http://jsontotable.com/ to create classes to represent my data and got the following:

```
public class Root
{
    public DateTime Facility {get;set;}
    public List<string> Address {get;set;}
    public List<string> City {get;set;}
    public List<string> State {get;set;}
    public List<string> ZipCode {get;set;}
    public List<string> AQDMID {get;set;}
    public int Jan {get;set;}
    public int Feb {get;set;}
    public int March {get;set;}
    public int April {get;set;}
    public int May {get;set;}
    public int June {get;set;}
    public int July {get;set;}
    public int Aug {get;set;}
    public string Sep {get;set;}
    public string Oct {get;set;}
    public string Nov {get;set;}
    public string Dec {get;set;}
    public int Total {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize my data using JSON.NET:

```
 List<Root> fetch = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);
```

But it doesn't deserialize to my C# class.

Comment: So you want to decen to C# Class Jason

Comment: Where did that class come from?  It seems quite wrong - e.g. Facility is a string, not a DateTime. Visual Studio will create the class for you

Comment: Personally, I stick to writing my own classes to hold any JSON data I have to interact with. It lets me make sure that the classes match what the JSON describes.

Comment: How is Facility a DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [json2cshap](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert data to C# classes, or the `Edit | Paste Special | Paste as JSON classes` menu option in Visual Studio. It seems that the service you use doesn't do a very good job of guessing what the fields represent.

Your class doesn't match your JSON:

```
"Facility": "H&S 01",
"Facility": "H&S 02",
```

These are *not* `DateTime` objects as declared in your model: `public DateTime Facility {get;set;}`

I'm a bit confused by your `int` and `string` Jan-Dec values, and your Total value. All of the values in your JSON are decimal, but in your C# model they're represented as integers and strings. I recommend using `double` or `decimal` for all of these.

A fixed class might look like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public string Facility { get; set; }
    public List<string> Address { get; set; }
    public List<string> City { get; set; }
    public List<string> State { get; set; }
    public List<string> ZipCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> AQDMID { get; set; }
    public double Jan { get; set; }
    public double Feb { get; set; }
    public double March { get; set; }
    public double April { get; set; }
    public double May { get; set; }
    public double June { get; set; }
    public double July { get; set; }
    public double Aug { get; set; }
    public double Sep { get; set; }
    public double Oct { get; set; }
    public double Nov { get; set; }
    public double Dec { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

Remember that your C# class should look like your data, and JSON.NET does a good job of telling you exactly where the problem lies. In attempting to deserialize your data into your class I got these two errors:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Could not convert string to DateTime: H&S 01. Path '[0].Facility', line 1, position 21.'

This led me to check the `Facility` field in your data and C# class.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Input string '222.0' is not a valid integer. Path '[0].Jan', line 1, position 131.'

Likewise, this led me to check the Jan-Dec values in your JSON data and C# class.

Note that you should actually provide this exception information in your question to assist people in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Just we need to change Root Class like 
and used it future .
[Json2Cshrap](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
 public class Root
    {
        public string Facility { get; set; }
        public List<string> Address { get; set; }
        public List<string> City { get; set; }
        public List<string> State { get; set; }
        public List<string> ZipCode { get; set; }
        public List<string> AQDMID { get; set; }
        public double Jan { get; set; }
        public double Feb { get; set; }
        public double March { get; set; }
        public double April { get; set; }
        public double May { get; set; }
        public double June { get; set; }
        public double July { get; set; }
        public double Aug { get; set; }
        public double Sep { get; set; }
        public double Oct { get; set; }
        public double Nov { get; set; }
        public double Dec { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If the answer I provided resolved your question, you should accept it rather than posting the code part as your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a C# class, you could use a dynamic object

Example:

```
string thejson = @"{
""error_code"": 0,
""access_token"": ""*******************"",
""expires_in"": 7200
}";

dynamic data = Json.Decode(thejson);
string theToken = data.access_token;
```

You will need System.Web.Helpers

Answer (score -3):

You need to create a structure something like this.

```
public class Data
{
     public List<Root> Root {get;set;}
}

public class Root
{
    public DateTime Facility {get;set;}
    public List<string> Address {get;set;}
    public List<string> City {get;set;}
    public List<string> State {get;set;}
    public List<string> ZipCode {get;set;}
    public List<string> AQDMID {get;set;}
    public int Jan {get;set;}
    public int Feb {get;set;}
    public int March {get;set;}
    public int April {get;set;}
    public int May {get;set;}
    public int June {get;set;}
    public int July {get;set;}
    public int Aug {get;set;}
    public string Sep {get;set;}
    public string Oct {get;set;}
    public string Nov {get;set;}
    public string Dec {get;set;}
    public int Total {get;set;}
}
```

Afterwards you should be able to deserilize it with

```
List<Root> fetch = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Comment: This offers no benefit over OP's code and doesn't work.